# how to compare more than two columns in sql

Tags: sql, compare

I have some Columns that I want to compare together.
my table:

| IssueId | ReqUntilResolved | ReqUntilReadyReleased | ReqUntilReleased | ReqUntilInvoice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 40 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 41 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 42 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I want to have another column that show if (ReqUntilReleased  = ReqUntilReadyReleased = ReqUntilDelivery =ReqUntilResolved)

```
SELECT 
    IssueID
    ,ReqUntilReleased 
    ,ReqUntilReadyReleased 
    ,ReqUntilDelivery 
    ,ReqUntilResolved 
    ,CASE WHEN  ReqUntilReleased= ReqUntilReadyReleased = ReqUntilDelivery = ReqUntilResolved
            THEN ReqUntilResolved
          ELSE 'Invalid'
     END AS Cumulative

FROM Table1
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN ( ReqUntilReleased = ReqUntilReadyReleased ) AND ( ReqUntilReadyReleased = ReqUntilDelivery ) AND ( ReqUntilDelivery = ReqUntilResolved  THEN xxx )`

Comment: I'm sure there's a more succint way to represent that, perhaps using the `ALL` operator.

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using